# How to get the filepath() of a file that a user browses for?

Tags: java, eclipse, filepath

```
JFileChooser file_chooser = new JFileChooser();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public void pick_me() throws FileNotFoundException {
    if(file_chooser.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = file_chooser.getSelectedFile();
        Scanner input=new Scanner(file);
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();

        while(input.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(input.nextLine());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        input.close();
    }
    else {
        sb.append("No file was selected");
    }
}
```

So this is the method that I am using to have the user browse for a file. I want to get the filepath of the file that a user chooses.

Comment: This line `String path = file.getAbsolutePath();` should give the path of the selected file. Do you expect something different?

Comment: Okay so basically what I want to be able to do is that, get a user to specify a file on my hard disk. And then I want to use a Jbutton to open that specific pdf file with that file path

Comment: Several questions: What do you mean by _open that specific pdf file_? Process that file programmatically or run some other application to open the file? And how is this question related to eclipse?